# Swap Azure Agent to Service

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a clean way to swap an azure agent to run as a service. When I installed it I decided to install to have run manually. As time has gone on the need to convert to a service is becoming bigger and bigger. Is there an easy way to convert it over to a service without having to reinstall an agent?

Could always just tell windows to run it as a service which I imagine would work, but any other thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could configure the self-hosted to run interactively or run as a service, if you have configured it run interactively, we can't change the way it works, if you want to change it, we need to remove and re-configure an agent

To remove the agent:

```
.\config remove
```

After you've removed the agent, you can [configure it again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-configure).

Comment: Thanks, I though this was going to be the case, just wanted to confirm I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, and I'd recommend just doing the remove/reconfigure if you can, but if you can't, this appears to do the job. It's based on [the agent's installer code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/src/Agent.Listener/Configuration.Windows/WindowsServiceControlManager.cs), but doesn't do all the steps (like [creating the `.service` file](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/08112695737d0fb8d16ab7282906b5a621b39944/src/Agent.Listener/Configuration.Windows/WindowsServiceControlManager.cs#L182-L192) or [creating the registry key](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/08112695737d0fb8d16ab7282906b5a621b39944/src/Agent.Listener/Configuration.Windows/NativeWindowsServiceHelper.cs#L789-L818)), so I wouldn't recommend this as a long-term solution.

Note that the service naming won't be the same as that produced by the installer, as the installer contains [a fair bit of logic](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/08112695737d0fb8d16ab7282906b5a621b39944/src/Agent.Listener/Configuration/ServiceControlManager.cs#L12-L78) to calculate the names.

All that aside, this does give you an agent running as a service, so it can be helpful while testing, particularly if (like me) you don't have sufficient access to re-run the configuration step.

```powershell
$accountName = "Insert account name here"
$resourceCollection = "Insert resource collection here"
$agentName = "Insert agent name here"
$pathToAgentService = "Insert path to AgentService.exe here (it'll be in the bin folder)"

$serviceName = "vstsagent.{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $accountName, $resourceCollection, $agentName
$serviceDisplayName = "Azure Pipelines Agent ({0}.{1}.{2})" -f $accountName, $resourceCollection, $agentName

sc.exe create "$serviceName" binPath= "$pathToAgentService" start=auto DisplayName="$serviceDisplayName" obj="NT Authority\NetworkService"
```

You'll probably want to change the service to run as an appropriate service account.